# How to add a label below a node

Tags: positioning, nodes

The below diagram was made by positioning the annotations manually:

[image: causal diagram]

I'd like to make the code easier to adapt. For example, make it easier to extend with some more annotated nodes.

It would help if the positioning of the annotations could be calculated automatically to give similar alignment.

Perhaps there is more that can be structured for ease of reading / modifying.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
        \draw[->] (0,0) node[left,font=\Large] (X) {A} -- (2,0) node[right,font=\Large] (Y) {Y}; 
        \node[below left=0.2 and -0.3,font=\tiny] (X_text) at (0, 0) {Asperine}; 
        \node[below right=0.2 and -0.15,font=\tiny] (Y_text) at (2, 0) {Stroke}; 
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this in one line by including `node`s and `label`s in the `\draw` command:

[image]

```
\draw[->](0,0)node[left, label={[label distance=-1mm]below:{\tiny Asperine}}]{\Large A}
    --(2,0)node[right, label={[label distance=-1mm]below:{\tiny Stroke}}]{\Large Y};
```

See section [17.10 The Label and Pin Options](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.10) in the PGF/TikZ Manual manual.

But it's more efficient (especially if you plan to use this in several different places in the document) to define a style using `tikzset`. That way you can make a change in one spot and it will change all locations in the document.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={font=\Large, label={[label distance=-1mm]below:{\tiny #1}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->](0,0)node[left, mynode=Asperine]{A}--(2,0)node[right, mynode=Stroke]{Y};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, if you want to place the nodes (rather than the arrow ends) at specific locations, you can use the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    mynode/.style={font=\Large, label={[label distance=-1mm]below:{\tiny #1}}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[mynode=Asperine](A) at (0,0){A};
\node[mynode=Stroke](B) at (2,0){Y};
\draw[->](A)--(B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: These are three great improvements. I will use them all. Thanks!

Comment: Another takaway: with `\tikzset`, the styles are setup to be re-used in multiple tikzpicture environments.

Comment: Is it possible to spread a label over multiple lines and apply center alignment?

Comment: @sjdh Yes, but I'm not sure I understand what you mean. You can try : `\node[label={[label distance=-1mm, text width = 3 cm,align=center]below:{Asperine\\ other\\ words}}](A) at (0,0){A};`

Comment: Multi line labels are possible. For example, use `label={[label distance=-1mm, align=center]below:{\small multi \\ line \\ label}}`. See https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.4.3

Answer (score 2):

Here's yet another approach using nodes shaped as multiparts, see ["shape rectangle split" in Ch. 71.6, tikz-manual](https://tikz.dev/library-shapes#sec-71.6). This can be useful, if you want to define a more complex text-object.

Main differences:

- define several `rectangle split`s, e.g. 3 in this example
- define own styles per `node` or `nodepart`, if useful

I outlied the default shape to better see the 3 parts. I used polar notation to move the connector a bit "upwards".

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    >={Stealth},    % providing some nicer arrow tips (make your choice)
    maj/.style={font={\Large},
                draw=teal!15,dashed,    % just to show the nodeparts shapes
                rectangle split,rectangle split parts=3},% <<< important
    anno/.style={font={\tiny}},
    cmnt/.style={font={\tiny\itshape},blue},
 ]
    % ~~~ nodes ~~~~~~~
    \node[maj] (A) at (0,0)
    {   A
        \nodepart[anno]{two} Asperine
        \nodepart[cmnt]{three} some comment
    };  
    \node[maj] (Y) at (3,0) 
    {   Y
        \nodepart[anno]{two} Stroke
        \nodepart[cmnt]{three} a different comment
        };
    
    % ~~~ connectors ~~~~~~
    \draw[->]               (A.25) -- (Y.160);  
    \draw[->,orange,dotted] (A)    -- (Y);      % just for reference
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's a wonderful visual summary. Thanks for pointing to relevant sections of the the tikz manual.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it. I suggest not to do too many things in one step, as it's easy, if not guaranteed, to get lost. Basic idea:

- separate actions
- place `\node`s with the main text, e.g. absolute as given below
- place annotation-`\node`s, reusing the aboves positions
- connect by lines of your choice
- introduce options as needed AND refactor them (move them) as styles to the beginning for heavy re-use
- doing clean code work pays off again and again

Some major mis-takes from your example:

- left and right are wrong and aren't need if you follow my approach
- you want to `[anchor=north]` the annotation nodes at the `south` positions of the main nodes, to automate placement
- for longer annotations you may want to introduce `align=center` in the `anno`-style AND put text like this in the node: `{some\\longer\\text};`

Depending on the complexity of your intended drawing or diagram you may want to combine the `maj` and `anno` actions in one `\pic` element, not done here, which you can place again and again. You may want to pass 2 arguments, main and annotation text.

You can rewrite your code using above's approach. The reuslting code will probably be hard to read, which opens the door for errors, glitches etc. However, that's a matter of preference.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
    %\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
    %\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    >={Stealth},    % providing some nicer arrow tips (make your choice)
    anno/.style={anchor=north,font={\tiny}},
    maj/.style={font={\Large}},
 ]
    % ~~~ nodes ~~~~~~~
    \node[maj] (A) at (0,0) {A};    
    \node[maj] (Y) at (3,0) {Y};
    
    % ~~~ annotations ~~~
    \node[anno] at (A.south) {Asperine};
    \node[anno] at (Y.south) {Stroke};
    
    % ~~~ connectors ~~~~~~
    \draw[->] (A) -- (Y);   
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I learned something about relative placements and alignment!